# Adding first date instances to a new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and have a pandas Dataframe containing three columns (and thousands of rows for each column):

1. Customer ID-numbers (sorted in ascending order), multiple ID's for some customers if they've received several offers/accepted several offers (dtype: int)
2. Date & time of an offer made to each customer (dtype : datetime64[ns])
3. Data & time if the customer accepted the offer in column 2, otherwise NaT.

What I would like to do is first find the date of the earliest offer made to each unique customer from column 2, and then find the earliest date each customer accepted an offer, if any (=column 3 has a date), and subtract from the date an offer was first accepted the date the first ever offer was made to the customer.

So this would give me the time range (preferably in days) between the time each customer first ever accepted an offer and the time the same customer was made his first ever offer. This time in days should be appended to a new column (it would list the same value for each individual customer if he accepted any offers, otherwise NaN.)

I tried doing this all sorts of ways, using pandas' .map together with lambda, creating helper columns and all sorts of functions but can't seem to figure it out.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Could you show an example of a subset of your data?

Comment: To clarify, do you want the time from the first acceptance to the first offer or the time from the first acceptance to the time that particular offer was made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say your data looks like this:

```
In [107]: data = pd.DataFrame({
   .....:     'Customer ID': pd.np.random.randint(0, 5, 10),
   .....:     'Date Offered': pd.Series(pd.np.random.randint(1429449000, 1429649000, 10) * 1E9).astype('datetime64[ns]'),
   .....:     'Date Accepted': pd.Series(pd.np.random.randint(1429449000, 1429649000, 10) * 1E9).astype('datetime64[ns]'),
   .....: })

In [108]: data.loc[data['Date Offered'] >= data['Date Accepted'], 'Date Accepted'] = None

In [109]: data
Out[109]:
   Customer ID       Date Accepted        Date Offered
0            2                 NaT 2015-04-21 14:04:45
1            2 2015-04-20 15:33:27 2015-04-20 00:25:48
2            2 2015-04-21 11:02:22 2015-04-20 17:09:48
3            1 2015-04-20 12:26:38 2015-04-19 15:22:32
4            1                 NaT 2015-04-21 07:19:44
5            0 2015-04-21 20:38:08 2015-04-21 13:55:29
6            1 2015-04-20 11:39:11 2015-04-19 16:42:37
7            2                 NaT 2015-04-21 14:45:51
8            4                 NaT 2015-04-20 07:26:14
9            3 2015-04-21 15:24:20 2015-04-21 03:44:49
```

You can find the difference between the first acceptance and first offer as follows:

```
In [110]: groups = data.groupby('Customer ID')

In [111]: diff = groups['Date Accepted'].min() - groups['Date Offered'].min()

In [112]: diff
Out[112]:
Customer ID
0   06:42:39
1   20:16:39
2   15:07:39
3   11:39:31
4        NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This can be added as a column to the data using:

```
In [113]: data['Diff'] = data['Customer ID'].map(diff)

In [114]: data
Out[114]:
   Customer ID       Date Accepted        Date Offered     Diff
0            2                 NaT 2015-04-21 14:04:45 15:07:39
1            2 2015-04-20 15:33:27 2015-04-20 00:25:48 15:07:39
2            2 2015-04-21 11:02:22 2015-04-20 17:09:48 15:07:39
3            1 2015-04-20 12:26:38 2015-04-19 15:22:32 20:16:39
4            1                 NaT 2015-04-21 07:19:44 20:16:39
5            0 2015-04-21 20:38:08 2015-04-21 13:55:29 06:42:39
6            1 2015-04-20 11:39:11 2015-04-19 16:42:37 20:16:39
7            2                 NaT 2015-04-21 14:45:51 15:07:39
8            4                 NaT 2015-04-20 07:26:14      NaT
9            3 2015-04-21 15:24:20 2015-04-21 03:44:49 11:39:31
```

Comment: Many thanks, this was exactly what my dataset looks like and the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a shot at this since I'm not sure I fully understand your dataframe.  Say you dataframe is `df` with columns `['ID', 'OfferDate', 'AcceptDate']`:

```
def func(group):
    group = group[~group['AcceptDate'].isnull()]
    group = group.sort('AcceptDate')
    first = group.iloc[0]
    first_elapsed = first['AcceptDate'] - first['OfferDate']
    return first_elapsed

df.groupby('ID').apply(func)
```